# Null reference on gameObject that has been successfully referenced

Tags: unity, gameobject, game-component

It's exactly as the title says. I am getting a null reference error even though I have properly referenced the object. I have debugged my code to show that the result is always exactly what I need however whenever put into practical use, the code returns an error.

```cs
                if(hit == true && canSee.transform.CompareTag("Unit"))
                {
                    //var Obehaviour = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>().Health; <--- Error is here.
                    float Health = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>().Health;
                    float fullHealth = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>().MaxHealth;
                    //Debug.Log("Object " + other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
                    //Debug.Log("Component and name " + Obehaviour.Name);
                    ReferenceScript.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
                    if(Health < fullHealth)
                    {
                        if(fullHealth - Health < Ubehaviour.supplies)
                        {
                            Health += Ubehaviour.supplyTransferRate;
                            Health = Mathf.Clamp(Health, 0, fullHealth);
                            other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>().UpdateHealth();
                            Ubehaviour.supplies -= Ubehaviour.supplyTransferRate;
                            Ubehaviour.supplies = Mathf.Clamp(Ubehaviour.Health, 0, Ubehaviour.maxSupplies);
                            Ubehaviour.LoseSupplies();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

As shown in the code above, I have tried to get the values I need by storing them in variables other than caching the entire class. But this also didn't work. What could be wrong? The debugs below work perfectly as well.

Comment: How can the error be on a comment line?

Comment: "Even though I have properly referenced the object" is not a claim we can verify from the information present here. Please edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example so that we can reproduce the problem you're seeing and test solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Obehaviour = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>().Health; <--- Error is here.
```

There are 3 reasons why this line could throw a NRE:

- `other` is null
- `other` doesn't have a parent
- the parent gameObject doesn't have a `UnitBehaviour`

Keep in mind that when you put this code snippet into some event handler (I suspect you have it in some OnTrigger* or OnCollision* method) then it might get triggered by an object you weren't expecting. It's always dangerous to have long chains of dereferentiations without any checks in between if one of them returns a `null` value.

If I was to debug this problem in my own code, I would break it up into individual lines so I can see which dereferentiation actually fails:

```
GameObject otherGameObject = other.gameObject;
Transform otherParent = otherGameObject.transform.parent;
UnitBehaviour parentUnitBehaviour = otherParent.gameObject.GetComponent<UnitBehaviour>();
var Obehaviour = parentUnitBehaviour.Health;
```

Another thing you can do is to wrap the whole code section into a `try { ... } catch NullReferenceException e { ...}` block and set a debugger breakpoint in the `catch` block. When the breakpoint triggers, you can examine what exactly you got in `other`. You might be in for a surprise.

Comment: Yeah I found the problem, the trigger was taking 2 others, since I had 2 colliders for a certain reason. One was a child of the prefab. One was the prefab. So it returned an error when it found the prefab instead of the child. Thanks!